# MySQL 8.0.23 Community Server Installation skips Configuration Part on windows 10

Tags: windows-10, installation, mysql

When i try to install MySQL 8.0.23 Community Server, it just skips the whole Product configuration part. Its going instantly to installation successfull. After that i cant do anything because theres no sql server instance to use. I installed it and uninstalled it multiple times and deleted corresponding files on two different machines. One machine is freshly setup laptop with nothing else on it. The weird thing is this works out of the box for fellow students. This step is in all Setup Tutorials.

Someone seemed to have this problem years ago but theres no solution. The guy just came to the conclusion that its a problem with the installer which i dont believe.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40520336/mysql-5-7-16-shows-no-product-configuration-option-during-installation-on-window

Comment: right click on the installer and choose "run as admin", is there any change?

Answer (score 0):

A guy on youtube who had the same problem gave me a solution

1. Launch again the installer you've downloaded
2. Click "Reconfigure" in Quick Action column
3. Reconfigure